# camera focus distance test

Tags: android, focus, camera

I'm developing an Android app that requires 2.3 Gingerbread. There's a functionality to get the subject distance in the camera, but on my phone it returns 0.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getFocusDistances(float[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getFocusDistances%28float%5B%5D%29)

Can someone with Gingerbread test this app in the attachment? It launches the camera and when you press the middle button on your phone, it prints out the subject distances. On my phone I get [auto,0,0,0]. Can anyone pls post what they get on their phone?

For the source code please see this question 
[Camera focus distances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401370/camera-focus-distances)

Here's the attachment
http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=645665&d=1309825196

Answer (score 0):

The source-code you reference works, but this measuring technique seems to be very anaccurate.
I think the camera hardware in most smartphones is unsuitable for this task.