# How can i monitor the current FocalLength of android Camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I have a `SurfaceView` that holds a Camera Preview.  I have set the camera focus mode to: `Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO`

and added an AutoFocus callback.  When i run the app, i can see the camera adjusting its' focus in real time, but the autoFocusCallback only ever gets fired once, and when it does, it always returns the same value. (2.95) regardless of how close or far i am from an in focus object.

Wondering what i am doing wrong.. is it even possible to get real time info on what the actual focal length is?

my **SurfaceView**, **onSurfaceChanged** code:

```
SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceHolderListener = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                camera=Camera.open();
            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
               camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

            }
                catch (Throwable e){ }
            }
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
            {

                Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
               Rect centralFocusArea = new Rect();
               centralFocusArea.set(holder.getSurfaceFrame().width()/2-10, holder.getSurfaceFrame().height()/2-10, holder.getSurfaceFrame().width()/2+10, holder.getSurfaceFrame().height()/2+10);

               ArrayList<Camera.Area> focusAreas = new ArrayList<Camera.Area>();
               focusAreas.add(new Camera.Area(centralFocusArea, 1000));

                //params.setPreviewSize(width, height);
                params.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
                params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
               // params.setFocusAreas(focusAreas);
                camera.setParameters(params);

                camera.startPreview();
                camera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.v("CAMERA", "FOCUS CHANGE:"+camera.getParameters().getFocalLength());
                        camera.getParameters().setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);

                    }
                });

            }
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0)
            {
                camera.stopPreview();
                camera.release();
            }

        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Android implementations do not provide a proper value for the focus distance, despite the parameter being well-defined in the Android specification. Some time ago, I checked three different cameras, and none of them provided useful information.

Comment: this is a huge Bummer..  i mean it is focus and re-focusing.. why can't i get the focus change even?

Comment: do you have any idea why it only fires the autofocus call back once?

Comment: My guess is that the camera is initially unfocused, then when you set the camera parameters it finds the correct focus at that time and then fires the autofocus callback. After that, as the camera tracks focus (if it does) it does not bother to call the autofocus callback. Camera focus implementation varies a great deal between cameras and does not always even implement the Android spec at all, let alone to the letter. I agree that it is frustrating!

Comment: but when i move the device after the initial callback i can see it refocusing, yet the call back is never called;

Comment: Others have the same problems. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401370/camera-focus-distances

Comment: oh well, i thought i had come up with a clever way to detect motion using the camera.. back to the drawing board

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you are confusing two different concepts: *focus distance* and *focal length*.

It seems you are interested in the **focus distance**, i.e. the distance for which the optical system has perfect focus; this depends on how far or close you are from in focus objects.

On the contrary, the **focal length** *is an intrinsic property of the optical system* (i.e. of the camera lenses), and it is fixed in most standard mobile devices (optical zoom capabilities are needed to have a variable focal length).
The value you get, 2.95, is the focal length (in mm) of your camera. Nexus 7 2013 tablets have such focal length.

Thus, it is perfectly normal that the function *getFocalLength()* always gives you the same value.